# how to read next sheet data of excel file?

Tags: excel, vb.net

My excel file has 29 sheets. I need to store all 29 data sheets in my database but the problem is it's reading the first sheet and then out of the loop.

My code is:

```
Dim result As DataSet = excelReader.AsDataSet()
For Each table As DataTable In result.Tables
    For i As Integer = 3 To 60
        code....
    Next
Next
```

The reader is showing[image]
But table showing the first data sheet. 
Should I change the condition in loop?

Comment: https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/issues/27

Comment: *My excel file has 29 sheets. I need to store all 30 data sheets in my database* - this sounds like a nice banker's anecdote. Are the sheets 29 or 30?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the name of the table that you want to skip, you may put a condition with that name:

```
For Each table As DataTable In result.Tables
    If table.Name <> "TheNameOfTheFirstSheet" Then
        code....
    End If
Next
```

---

There should be a way to refer to the table by its index. Thus, you can avoid the first table. I guess something like this should work:

```
for count = 2 to result.Tables.Count
    For i As Integer = 3 To 60  
        result.Tables(i) = 
    Next
Next
```